# Trabalhando com RadioButton e RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, radiobutton

Estou tentando fazer uma tela onde o usuário teria que escolher entre as opções em `<RadioButton` e se ele escolhe a certa contabiliza para o certo e caso contrário para o errado, tendo como finalizado, após clicar em "Responder" igual está no print e no pedaço de código abaixo:

[image: RadioBtn]

```
    public void onClickView(View rdio){
    int qnt_certo = 0, qnt_errado = 0;
      RadioGroup rd_group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.perguntas);
        switch (rd_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
          case R.id.rd_btn1:
              qnt_errado = qnt_errado+1;
              break;
          case R.id.rd_btn2:
              qnt_errado = qnt_errado+1;
              break;
          case R.id.rd_btn3:
              qnt_certo = qnt_certo +1;
              break;
          case R.id.rd_btn4:
              qnt_errado = qnt_errado+1;
              break;
        }
    }
```

Mas a parte em que eu encontrei dificuldade foi a de manipular as informações, vou explicar:

Quero que após o usuário escolher e clicar em **Responder** aquele `<RadioGroup` ficaria bloqueado, assim sendo ele não poderia alterar sua escolha e seu "voto" contabilizado.
Minhas dificuldades:

1- Saber quando e o que o usuário escolheu.

2- Bloquear a `<RadioGroup`quando ele **Responder**

3- Enviar as informações para outra `activity` para ele ter um percentual de acertos e erros

4- Após escolhido a `<RadioButton` trocar a cor (caso esteja certo ou errado)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método **setOnCheckedChangeListener** do RadioGroup da seguinte forma:

```
final RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.group);
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton button = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            String resposta = button.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Com isso você tem o RadioButton selecionado, podendo assim alterar a cor, obter o texto, alterar o texto ou qualquer outra operação de RadioButton.

Para desabilitar o RadioGroup você precisa desabilitar todos os elementos dentro dele. Isso pode ser feito com a seguinte função:

```
private void disableAllOptions(RadioGroup group) {
    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
        group.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Essa função pode ser chamada dentro do listener, da seguinte forma:

```
final RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.group);
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton button = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            String resposta = button.getText().toString();

            disableAllOptions(group);
        }
    });
```

Para enviar os valores para outra Activity você deve utilizar os métodos *putExtra* na Intent que você utilizar para iniciar a outra Activity.